# Вычесление даты Unix

Tags: php

Как можно вычеслить какая дата будет через три дня в unix

Comment: Текущая плюс три дня, и не только в unix.

Comment: текущая+ 60 сек * 60 мин * 24ч * 3д

Comment: @Mike  спасибо оформите как ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дата в Unix - количество секунд прошедших с 1 января 1970 года. Так что 3 дня это

```
60 сек * 60 мин * 24ч * 3д = 259200 секунд
```